# Combining the use of preceding and following sibling in the same xpath query

Tags: xpath

I have a quite simple problem but i can't seem to resolve it. Let's say i have the following code:

```
<a>
    <b property="p1">zyx</b>
    <b>wvu</b>
    <b>tsr</b>
    <b property="p2">qpo</b>
    <b>qcs</b>
</a>
```

I want to select the nodes between the `b` node who has a `property="p1"` and the `b` node who has `property="p2"`. I can do either of those with the preceding-sibling and the following-sibling axis but I can't seem to find how to combine both.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for solutions in XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**XPath 1.0**:

```
/a/b[preceding-sibling::b/@property='p1' and following-sibling::b/@property='p2']
```

**XPath 2.0:**
The expression above has some quirks in XSLT 2.0, it is better to use the new and safer operators `<<` (before) and `>>` (after).

```
/a/b[../b[@property='p2'] << . and . >> ../b[@property='p1']]
```

Comment: It's looks like we were thinking in this at the same time. Ja!

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, but I think using "and" is safer than using a sequence of two predicates.

Answer (score 8):

Also, this XPath 1.0:

```
/a/b[preceding-sibling::b/@property='p1'][following-sibling::b/@property='p2']
```

**Note**: Don't use `//` as first step. Whenever you can replace `and` operator by predicates, do it.

In XPath 2.0:

```
/a/b[. >> ../b[@property='p1']][../b[@property='p2'] >> .]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, exactly what i need. But i'm curious as to why would you replace and by another predicate ?

Comment: @raph.amiard: From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans: "An and expression is evaluated by evaluating each operand". So, if left operand is false, right operand will be evaluate any way. With predicates, only for those nodes that pass first filter, the second predicate will be apply on them. For XPath 2.0, this MAY be not the case.

Comment: Was trying this solution and it works great. However what if eh example above had another <b property="p2"> downline? How do you stop at the first occurrence?

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the tests in the predicate using `and`.

Comment: Indeed, spelled out it would read something like: `//b[preceding-sibling::b/@property='p1' and following-sibling::b/@property='p2']`

Comment: Wrikken : ok thank you. I didn't know i could use preceding and following sibling like that, i only ever saw it used like "b[@property="p1"]/following-sibling::*"


Paul Butcher : i knew that, but thank you for taking the time to answer