# Group Nodes / content with preceding-sibling and following-sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have:

XML

```
<TestCases>
   <TestCase>
       <TestCaseElement>
                    <Name><![CDATA[Start]]></Name>
                    <Role><![CDATA[TESTSTEP]]></Role>
       </TestCaseElement>
       <TestCaseElement>
                    <Name><![CDATA[Content]]></Name>
                    <Role><![CDATA[TESTSTEP]]></Role>
                    <Code>
                       <Line><![CDATA[some Content]></Line>
                       <Line><![CDATA[some Content]></Line>
                    </Code>

       </TestCaseElement>
       <TestCaseElement>
                   <Name><![CDATA[End]]></Name>
                   <Role><![CDATA[TESTSTEP]]></Role>
       </TestCaseElement>
     **n of these Start-Content-Stop Triplets are in the XML Document**
  </TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

I want to "group" this Elements with XSLT.

Each group should start with **Start** and should end with **End**
My first idea was to  do that with this solution: [stackoverflow combining xslt issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388923/combining-the-use-of-preceding-and-following-sibling-in-the-same-xpath-query)

This would be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement[../TestCaseElement[Name='Step-Start'] << . and . >> ../TestCaseElement[Name='Step-End']]">
```

But I think I should group with ***key*** and / or ***generate-id*** and use ***following-sibling*** and ***preceding-sibling***

> My desired output: I want to have all the Content that is precise covered by the Start and End Element.

It is not clear how to ask for the Name **Start** because this is one tier under the *TestCaseElement* wich i want to "group"?

How can I access each group if they is available some day.

Comment: Your expected output is shown as empty. I assume that this is an editing mistake. Please correct and show expected output. Any answer given to this question will be based around xsl:for-each-group . I suggest you search on that instruction and read about it.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491108

Comment: Hi, i have edited the desired Output. It unfortunately slipped outside the textblock.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="TestCase">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="TestCaseElement" group-starting-with="*[Name='Start']">
    <group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i try to test this, the current-group selection is new to me.  Outside the <xsl:template match="TestCase"> i need somethin like <xsl:template match="current-group">

 </xsl:template>  ? how is this exactly defined, the w3c output is not really example-driven...

Comment: The apply-templates here processes each node in the current group individually. You will need a template rule that matches each of those nodes (individually) and does whatever processing you want to do on that node.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 2.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="TestCase">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
  <xsl:for-each-group select="TestCaseElement" group-starting-with="*[Name='Start']">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()
     [not(. >> current-group()/self::*[Name='End'])]"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...will take this input document, slightly adapted for clarity from your sample input, and expanded to increase test coverage range...**

```
<TestCases>
    <TestCase>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name>Start</Name>
            <Role>TESTSTEP 1</Role>
        </TestCaseElement>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name>Content 1</Name>
            <Role>TESTSTEP</Role>
            <Code>
                <Line>some Content 1</Line>
                <Line>some Content 1</Line>
            </Code>
        </TestCaseElement>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name>End</Name>
            <Role>TESTSTEP 1</Role>
        </TestCaseElement>
        <TestCaseElement>
            This content is dropped because it is
            not between a Start and End TestCaseElement.
        </TestCaseElement>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name>Start</Name>
            <Role>TESTSTEP 2</Role>
        </TestCaseElement>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name>Content 2</Name>
            <Role>TESTSTEP</Role>
            <Code>
                <Line>some Content 2</Line>
                <Line>some Content 2</Line>
            </Code>
        </TestCaseElement>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name>End</Name>
            <Role>TESTSTEP 2</Role>
        </TestCaseElement>
    </TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

**...and yield this output, as per stated requirements...**

```
<TestCases>
   <TestCase>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Name>Start</Name>
         <Role>TESTSTEP 1</Role>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Name>Content 1</Name>
         <Role>TESTSTEP</Role>
         <Code>
            <Line>some Content 1</Line>
            <Line>some Content 1</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Name>End</Name>
         <Role>TESTSTEP 1</Role>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Name>Start</Name>
         <Role>TESTSTEP 2</Role>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Name>Content 2</Name>
         <Role>TESTSTEP</Role>
         <Code>
            <Line>some Content 2</Line>
            <Line>some Content 2</Line>
         </Code>
      </TestCaseElement>
      <TestCaseElement>
         <Name>End</Name>
         <Role>TESTSTEP 2</Role>
      </TestCaseElement>
   </TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

### Notes

Notice that only the TestCaseElement elements bounded by a demarcated Start and End are retained. Other nodes outside this grouping are dropped. Also some efficiency may be gained by putting into a variable...

```
current-group()/self::*[Name='End']
```

... so that this expression does not need to be re-computed for each member of the current-group().