# Combining the use of preceding- and following-sibling in the same XPath query up to first instance

Tags: xpath, siblings, find-occurrences

Following the post here [Combining the use of preceding and following sibling in the same xpath query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388923/combining-the-use-of-preceding-and-following-sibling-in-the-same-xpath-query) I am wanting to do the same except I want to get nodes up to the **first occurrence** of p2.

So the modified example data is

```
<a>
    <b property="p1">zyx</b>
    <b>wvu</b>
    <b>tsr</b>
    <b>dcv</b> 
    <b property="p2">qpo</b>
    <b>qcs</b>
    <b property="p2">wee</b>
    <b>tbg</b>
    <b>rty</b>
    <b property="p2">qwe</b>
    <b>jkl</b>
</a>
```

I have tried

```
/a/b[preceding-sibling::b/@property='p1' and following-sibling::b[1]/@property='p2']
```

which gives me dcv, qcs, and rty. 
Then I tried

```
/a/b[preceding-sibling::b/@property='p1' and (following-sibling::b/@property='p2')[1]]
```

which gives me wvu, tsr, dcv, qpo, qcs, wee, tbg, and rty.

What I actually need is from p1 to the first p2 or wvu, tsr, and dcv. I have tried almost every combination of [1] but have failed and would like some help on the construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/a/b[preceding-sibling::b/@property='p1' and not(preceding-sibling::b/@property='p2' or @property='p2')]
```

It checks if a given `b` element has a *preceding-sibling* named `p1` and is not a *preceding-sibling* of `p2` or `p2` itself. That's all.

Comment: Very clever answer. Being relatively new to xpath i didn't know how to put it together. Many thanks.